# $_POST Issue with Array

Tags: php, arrays, post, error-handling

I am getting an error on the `if (in_array($_POST['band', $bands] === false))`line and I am not sure why. I am trying to make an error array for my inputs on my forms. Does the `$_POST[  ,  ]` need to be formatted another way or do I leave one of them out and only keep the selected 'band' that is in the form?

**Error:** Parse error: syntax error, unexpected token ",", expecting "]"

```
$bands = array("ACDC", "Journey", "Modest Mouse", "Band of Horses", "Vampire Weekend", "Of Monsters and Men", "Broken Bells", "Phoenix", "Fleetwood Mac", "AJR");
if (in_array($_POST['band', $bands] === false))
    {$errors[] = 'Please select a band.';}
```

This is the form drop-down for this specific error trap.

```
<input type = "text" name = "band">
            <label>Band: </label>
                <select name="band" size="1">
                    <option value = "default">Choose One</option>
                    <option value = "ACDC">ACDC</option>
                    <option value = "Journey">Journey</option>
                    <option value = "Modest Mouse">Modest Mouse</option>
                    <option value = "Band of Horses">Band of Horses</option>
                    <option value = "Vampire Weekend">Vampire Weekend</option>
                    <option value = "Of Monsters and Men">Of Monsters and Men</option>
                    <option value = "Broken Bells">Broken Bells</option>
                    <option value = "Phoenix">Phoenix</option>
                    <option value = "Fleetwood Mac">Fleetwood Mac</option>
                    <option value = "AJR">AJR</option>
                </select>
```

Comment: It should probably be `if (in_array($_POST['band'], $bands) === false)`

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per Chris Haas (Thank you!),

It should probably be if (in_array($_POST['band'], $bands) === false)